# Possible to run oracle package from sql plus without compiling it into a database?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have a certain oracle package file (pbk with pks). I want to execute one of the methods in the package from sqlplus. I want to do so without compiling the package into the oracle database.

Is this possible ? if so how ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an [anonymous PLSQL block](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Anonymous_block) to run something without compiling to the database, but objects that don't exist in the database (package, function, stored procedure, type, etc) need to be declared within the PLSQL anonymous block.

That means you'll have to copy the method(s) you want to test from the package/etc, pasting them within the PLSQL block:

```
DECLARE

  FUNCTION your_fnc() RETURN ... AS ...

BEGIN

  SELECT your_fnc()
    FROM DUAL;

END;
```